What duration should I choose when applying for a 1 year multi entry Schengen visa?
I'm hoping to get a 1-year multi-entry Schengen visa. I have used three visas within the previous 2 years so I believe I already qualify for the Visa Code rule for multiple-entry visa.
My question is what duration should I choose when applying for a 1 year multi entry Schengen visa? I get this field in the Schengen application form. Should I still choose short stay even if I'm hoping to get 1-year visa?


This question is similar to: How do I ask for a long validity Schengen visa?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Should I still choose short stay even if I'm hoping to get 1-year visa?

Yes.  A long-stay visa (also known as a "national visa" or a "type D" visa) is a visa that allows you to stay for longer than 90 days at once, which as you seem to be aware is not what a one-year multiple-entry visa allows.  You're applying for a short-stay ("type C") visa, albeit one that is valid for multiple entries over a period of 1 year.
In other words, short-stay vs. long-stay refers to the conditions of your visits ("stays") rather than to the duration of the visa's validity.
You probably know this, but for the sake of completeness I will mention it nonetheless: with a one-year multiple-entry visa, your visits to the Schengen area will be governed by the so-called 90/180 rule, namely that for every 180-day period, you must have no more than 90 days of presence in the Schengen area.

Great, thanks! That clear things up. Then to increase my likelihood of getting a 1-yr visa, I can just probably create an itinerary that spans 6mos or more. And also indicate in the cover letter that I'm requesting/hoping to get a 1-yr visa. Right?

@SigMendez Just to clarify--you mean an itinerary that lists multiple trips over the course of six months or more?

Yes, I will submit an itinerary that lists multiple trips over 6 months, going in out of countries within Schengen and non-Schengen areas. That would help my case right?

@SigMendez unfortunately I don't have any relevant experience with actual applications for extended-duration visas, so I can only speculate about the best strategy to obtain one.  I would avoid making up a fictitious itinerary, but if you have even tentative plans for future trips it probably won't hurt to mention them and likely it would help.
